# How to set up a signup form with two screens in Xcode using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile, authentication

I am setting up a signup form for an app in xcode and I am trying to use two screens for the form. The first view controller has first and last name and the second view controller has email and password.

What is the best way to set this up to pass the data from the first screen to the second screen to create an account? I am using swift 2.0.

Comment: You could just pass the data by overriding the `prepareForSegue` function. Unrelated, the user who removed the `xcode` and `mobile` tags was correct. These tags are unnecessary for this question.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the answer and reference to the other question. Helped out a lot!

Comment: Could you tell me which backend you are using?

Comment: @DanL Using Firebase, eventually will move to mysql on aws (backend langauge = python)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know much about Firebase because I use Parse. On the first screen, get the user's username and password and then send it up to Parse. Now the user has the ability to log in. On the next page(s), ask for all of the other details that you need. If the app crashes or the user leaves the app before completing the second page, you'll need to have the account page ready to handle the absence of, say, the user's name and picture. In my app, I first check if the data is available and then display it. If it is missing, I display a red button that allows the user to enter that information.